# Add Button in Scroll view --> view will not load on startup

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am new to Iphone developing and i have a very basic problem for which i couldn't find any answers yet:

My aim is to have a ScrollView inside a TabbarApplication, and have several buttons with different functionalities on the pages of the scrollview. 
I downloaded some sample code for ScrollView inside a TabBar, but the very second i added a Button to the View that should show up as the Scroll Views first page (which is empty besides having a label and that button) its's content won't appear anymore, until the first click/scroll-attempt.

I'd like to post some code..but basically there is none except from autogenerated stuff out of IB. All I did was add a Button in the .xib via IB and connect it to an IBAction and voila: stuff won't show ;)

Thanks in advance for any help,

Arne

**Edit**: To clarify things, the button and label themselves working fine, but only gets shown *after* the first scroll attempt. Before i added a button to the projekt (was only a page with a label) the label was shown right from the start of the App!

Comment: add button under scrollview in .xib

Comment: but i want to have different button functionality for the different pages of the scroll view...is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the following:

- Change the scrollview background to a color (i.e. [UIColor redColor])
- Double check that the code has an IBOutlet to the button the following way:

.h File

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton* myButton;
```

.m File

```
@synthesize myButton;
```

- Double check that from the XIB file, the button is added to the scrollview, and that the IBOutlet is connected to the code.
- To debug it, put a breakpoint in viewWillAppear method in your viewController, and check if your 'myButton' is not nil.

That should make the button appear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I checked that and the IBoutlet is connected. The thing is - the button _does_ appear, together with the rest of the page, but only after the first user input (any touch anywhere). Before that it only shows the PageControl and the background colour

Comment: Can you explain where do you touch? You mean you touch inside the scrollview, or you tap in a button on the tabbar from tabBarController?

Comment: I actually got it to work today morning, the problem was indeed in the viewWillAppear from the example project that i used. I still don't know why exactly the project worked _before_ I added the button, but it's not all that important. Thank you a lot for your time and efford! :)